# I am have an Activity and bind two fragment using FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I have an `Activity` and bind two fragment using `FragmentPagerAdapter`, we have one String variable that have null values.I'm calling a method and pass the results in string, when we return from second fragment string values show a null, but when we call

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser);
```

its show values.but i am not want to use this method.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: thanks @quick learner for your response, we solve its another ways.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom ViewPager and setOffscreenPageLimit(0) in your code 
Here is the code of CustomViewPager

[click here for CustomVIewPager](http://putul.io/s7wSVlxEh)

If you face any problem fell free to ask me.

Comment: thanks @Vishal Sojitra for your response,Actually problem is occurred on re-initialized fragment class.